# ¿Qué diferencias existen entre la asignación por =, -> o ->>?

Tags: r

La asignación de una variable en R puede hacerse de dos formas, la más habitual y extendida es:

```
variable <- valor
```

aunque también podremos hacerlo así:

```
variable <<- valor
```

Y por último también podremos hacerlo usando el `=` como en casi todos los otros lenguajes de programación.

```
variable = valor
```

#### ¿Qué diferencias existen (si las hay) entre estas formas de asignación?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El detalle de las operaciones de asignación están muy bien documentadas en : [Assignment Operators](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html). Hay una clara diferencia de funcionalidad entre `<-` y `=` con respecto a `<<-`.

#### Asignación mediante `<<-`

Esta tiene sentido dentro de una función, la idea es que el valor a asignar se evaluará en el contexto de la función y en caso de no encontrarse, se evaluará el entorno global:

```
x <- 5
mifuncion <- function() {ret <<- x;ret}
mifuncion()
[1] 5
```

En este ejemplo `x` es un objeto no definido dentro de la función sino fuera de esta, por lo que funciona la asignación "global". Sin embargo si el valor estuviera definido dentro de la función, sería éste el utilizado

```
miotrafuncion <- function() {x <- 'otro valor';ret <<- x;ret}
miotrafuncion()
[1] "otro valor"
```

Esto funciona también a la hora de modificar el valor de una variable del entorno "global":

```
x <- 5
mifuncion <- function() {x <<- 10}
mifuncion()
x
[1] 10
```

#### Asignación mediante `<-` o `=`

En el contexto de una asignación simple: `variable <- valor` o `variable = valor`, la funcionalidad es similar, la asignación normal de variables en el entorno actual. La forma que pareciera ser la más aceptada en la comunidad es la de `<-`, a contramano del operador de asignación más habitual en la mayoría de los lenguajes que es el `=`. Esto por que sin duda `<-` tiene algunas particularidades que la hacen más flexible y útil, veamos:

- **Asignación en ambos sentidos**: Podremos hacer tanto `variable <- valor` como `valor -> variable`. Esto es muy cómodo, es normal que evaluemos varias veces una sentencia de múltiples líneas (por ejemplo cuando usamos el `+` o  `%>%`) y luego cuando estemos seguros asignemos el resultado a una variable, si ingresamos primero la variable, deberemos reformatear completamente el código sin embargo es totalmente válido hacer algo así:

  ```
  df %>% 
      group_by(Tratamiento) %>% 
      filter(Ronda == min(Ronda)) -> new.df
  ```
- **Asignación y uso simultáneo**: Si queremos crear un vector y pasárselo por parámetro a una función en forma simultanea, podemos hacerlo de forma muy compacta:

  ```
  > mean(x <- 1:10)
  [1] 5.5
  > x
   [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
  > mean(x = z <- 1:10) # O si queremos asignar otra variable
  z
   [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
  ```
- **Asignación prácticamente a cualquier nivel**: Podríamos asignar una variable y evaluarla inmediatamente:

  ```
  if (x<-1) {print("si")} # Cualquier valor <> 0 se evalúa como TRUE
  [1] "si"
  ```

  Sin embargo esto no es posible usando `=`

  ```
  if (x=1) {print("si")}
  Error: inesperado '=' in "if (x="
  ```

**Aclaración para los puristas**: Si bien se puede emular los dos últimos ejemplos usando el `=` mediante los `()`:

```
mean((x = z <- 1:10))
```

o

```
if ((x=1)) {print("si")}
```

siendo estricto, es funcionalidad adicional, los `()` actúan como la función **identidad** es decir `function(x) x`, es decir se evalúa y retorna el parámetro.